# Change original variable value by changing value of passed function parameter

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to change the variable value with function like example below? Whenever I change the passed parameter value the original value doesn't change. Why is this happening?

```js
let b = 3;
function t(n) {
    n = 5; 
}

t(b)
console.log(b) // still 3
```

I know this can be done like this, but I am wondering why the example above wont work.

```js
let b = 3;

function t() {
    return 5;
}

b = t();
console.log(b)
```

Comment: JavaScript, like many other languages uses *pass by value*, not *pass by reference*. So what you want is not possible in that exact way. There are workarounds though. However, in such a simple case, returning the value and letting the caller decide how what to do with it seems the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing scalar values to function will pass them by value, not by reference.

One solution would be to pass it as object:

```js
let b = {value: 3};

function t(n) {
    n.value = 5; 
}

t(b);
console.log(b.value);
```

Comment: Objects are also passed by value but the value is a (different kind of) reference. You wouldn't be able to do `n = {value: 5}` either.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, you are right, it's passed as shallow copy - only inner properties can be changed

Comment: It's not a copy, otherwise making changes to it wouldn't have any effect on the "original" object.